# Get a while loop to run "X" number of times with two conditions in PHP

Tags: php, database, while-loop

So i have this code:

```
<?php


require_once('../../ccconnect.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM orgs";

$response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

if($response){
echo '<table align="left" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="8"> 
<tr> 
<td align="left"> <b>Logga</b> </td>
<td align="left"> <b>Namn</b> </td>
<td align="left"> <b>Andel till ändamål</b> </td>
<td align="left"> <b>Vinst</b> </td> </tr>';


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response))){

    echo '<tr> 
    <td align="left">' . $row['logo'] . '</td> 
    <td align ="left">' . $row['name'] . '</td>
    <td align ="left">' . $row['chare'] . '</td>
    <td align ="left">' . $row['profit'] . '</td>';

    echo '</tr>';



}


echo '</table>';

} else {
echo "Kunde inte genomföra databaskomandot<br>";
echo mysqli_error($dbc);
}

?>
```

The code will print out a table of results from my database, but i want to limit the results i get to only show 5 results for example. How would i do this?

Comment: That's not all the code, figured that only this was needed to get my question answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `LIMIT` clause in SQL.

`SELECT * FROM my_table
LIMIT 5;`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit the query or limit the loop. (I like the first option better).

You have this query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM orgs";
```

Wanna get 5 results only?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM orgs LIMIT 5";
```